# Damm during Hajj

Tags: hajj, kaffarah

Just a quick question. What happens to the Damm which is the animal sacrifice performed to atone for violations of certain restrictions during Hajj? Will it be eaten by the person and distributed to the poor?

Comment: What do you mean by "Damm"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a sacrifice becomes obligatory on a pilgrim due to some violation of the restrictions of Ihram, then it is not permissible for the said pilgrim to eat from it. Rather he must give it away as charity to the poor.

**Ref:**

> الفدية التي تذبح عن فعل محظور أو ترك واجب توزع  على مساكين الحرم ... ولا يأكل منها من وجبت عليه شيئا؛ لأنها كفارة
>
> A sacrificial animal which is slaughtered for having committed a prohibited act or omitting an obligation should be distributed among
> the poor of Al-Haram ... Whoever offers this ransom should not eat from the meat of the sacrificial animal because it is an expiation.
>
> <sup>—  [Fatwas of Permanent Commitee](https://shamela.ws/book/21772/6762) - [[English translation](https://archive.org/details/en_10_Majmoo_alFatawa_IFTAA_COLL02/en_10_Majmoo_alFatawa_IFTAA_COLL02/page/n251/mode/2up)]</sup>